# Find the maximum of a function with 4 parameters

Tags: functions

I'm trying to find the maximum of a function with 4 positive parameters :
$$f(x,y,z,t)=(2x+2)+(4y-1)+(3z+4)+(5t+3)$$
with $x+y+z+t = 50$

I don't know if this is feasible and how to proceed.
I have try to reduce the function with $t = 50-x-y-z$ so : $$f(x,y,z) = (2x+2)+(4y-1)+(3z+4)+(253-x-y-z)$$

But I don't know what to do after that.
Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: And what is $w$, if you  please?

Comment: No harm here to set $z=t=0$, the maximum is $+\infty$ even then. Too few constraints. Maybe $x,y,z,t$ are positive?

Comment: Sorry I forget to write that $x,y,z$ and $t$ are positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is linear but you have no linear inequality constraints on your variables and technically, in this case, there might not be a maximum to your function (i.e. you could find better and better solutions). For example, just set $x = 50$, $y = 0$, and $t = -z$. A linear equation alone is in general not enough to constrain an optimization problem to a finite optimal value.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying correctly you have
$$f(x,y,w) = 8+2x+4y+3z+250-5x-5y-5z
           = 258-3x-y-2z$$
If there are no restrictions on $x,y,z$ let $y,z=0$ and drive $x \to -\infty$.

If $x,y,z$ must be non-negative, clearly the best you can do is when $x=y=z=0$...